# get 2 images next to each other instead of 1 in listviewbuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to get the 2 images next to each other instead of beneath each other but I have no clue how to go about something like this, I tried something with an I variable to influence the index but that did not really work out. normally I could do this but with the index, I have no clue how to go about this.

code:

```
Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            _items.isNotEmpty
                ? Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _items.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      RawMaterialButton(
                        child: Image(
                          image: NetworkImage(_items[index]["portrait"]),
                          height: 200,
                          width: 140,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.push(context, _AnimatedNavigation(SpecificCharacterRoute(
                              _items[index]["name"], _items[index]["name"], _items[index]["shop_background"], _items[index]["overview"],
                              _items[index]["difficulty"], "images/dbdsurvivorlogo.png")
                            )
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              ),
            )
                : Container()
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Here's an image of what I mean
[image]

Here's an image of what I have

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GridView.count(` with  `crossAxisCount: 2,`

```dart
 GridView.count(
  crossAxisCount: 2,
  children: [...],
);
```

Or with `.builder`

```dart
GridView.builder(
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
  ),
  itemCount: ,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {...},
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Gridview for 2 in a row. If you want to change from 2 to 3 in row then you can change **crossAxisCount**.

```
GridView.builder(
                gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                    maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 20),
                itemCount: _items.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, index) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      RawMaterialButton(
                        child: Image(
                          image: NetworkImage(_items[index]["portrait"]),
                          height: 200,
                          width: 140,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.push(context, _AnimatedNavigation(SpecificCharacterRoute(
                              _items[index]["name"], _items[index]["name"], _items[index]["shop_background"], _items[index]["overview"],
                              _items[index]["difficulty"], "images/dbdsurvivorlogo.png")
                            )
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                }),
```

Comment: If i try this code its saying "The named parameter 'crossAxisCount' isn't defined"

Comment: Can you share Screenshot of error.

Comment: I already fixed it with "Files > Invalidate Caches / Restart" in android studio :)

Comment: Great. Keep it up.